# AngularJS app and separate index.html

Tags: angularjs, express

I have typically used Angular to create whole websites rather than for parts of a website but now I would like to separate the homepage for SEO purposes so that it's a static HTML file and not part of the AngularJS app.

I'm using ExpressJS on the back-end but I'm not sure how I would serve the `index.html` and the `app/index.html` separately. Could someone point me in the right direction?

In `server.js` I normally have something like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index.html');
});
```

but what do I need to do to be able to deliver `index.html` if the user goes to the homepage and `app/index.html` if the user navigates to `/somewhere`

I'm trying to avoid the cost of an extra Heroku Application fee if at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

See the code below. You will setup a rule wherein if the url is /home (or whatever your homepage path is), you send the user to index.html and after all the rules (if you have more rules) you will have a catchall rule where you will send user to app/index.html.

```
app.route('/home')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });

app.route('/*')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index.html');
    });
};
```